# Multiple linear regression slopes inconsistent with graph - why?

Tags: regression, interaction, linear-model, regression-coefficients

I am doing a multiple linear regression, with 3 categorical predictor variables (Flow, Drug, Pesticide) each with two levels (0 vs. 1). The response variable is the abundance of invertebrates. I have set the predictors as categorical variables using the function as.factor(). I am interested in finding out the significance of the factor main effects and the 2-way and 3-way interactions.

This is my code:

```
lm_abund<-lm(Benth_TotalAbund ~ Flow*Drug*Pesticide, data=benth, contrasts = list(Flow = "contr.sum", Drug = "contr.sum", Pesticide = "contr.sum"))

summary(lm_abund, type = "III")
```

It then produces this output:

[image]

This is the 3-way interaction graph that ecapsulates everything:

```
cat_plot(lm_abund, pred = Drug , modx = Pesticide, mod2 = Flow, geom="line", interval = FALSE, data = benth, y.label = "Invert Abundance", mod2.labels = c("0", "1"), main. Title = "Flow")
```

[image]

My question is: **Why does Flow1 have a negative direction of effect (as indicated by the slope), when Flow1 clearly leads to a generally higher invertebrate abundance as per the graph?** You can even see it on the controls, which are coded as zero. I expected that the sign of the slope should be positive. You can also see for the 3-way interaction of Flow1:Drug1:Pesticide1 that it clearly leads to higher invert abundance but the slope is negative (-141.09)!

I am analysing several response variables (besides invertebrate abundance) with the same predictor variables and, in many of them, the signs of the slopes are inconsistent with how they look when graphed. Hope someone can help with this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the model is coded the way you think it is.

```
> contr.sum(factor(0:1))
  [,1]
0    1
1   -1
>  contr.treatment(factor(0:1))
  1
0 0
1 1
```

The number labelled `Flow1` in your output estimates
$$0.5\times(\text{mean when flow==0}-\text{mean when flow==1})$$
averaged over `Pesticide` and `Drug`.  That is, they have the opposite sign to the treatment contrasts that would give you `flow=1` minus `flow=0`.  The coefficient of -209 means that flow=0 is lower on average by about 418 than flow=1.

If you ran a model with no interactions and ran it with both `contr.sum` and `contr.treatment`, the coefficients would differ by a factor of -1/2.

It's really worth starting off with a main effects model so that you can see this sort of thing in a setting that's easier to understand